# SCSS importing not fully working

Tags: sass

I am having trouble connecting files.

**file style.scss**

```
@import 'foundation/foundation';
```

**file foundation/_foundation.scss**

```
/**
  Some comment
*/

@import '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/normalize-scss/sass/normalize';
```

**outputed file style.css**

```
/**
  Some comment
*/
```

As you can see I am getting only comment, no imported CSS rules.

Here are my gulp tasks

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./app/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('./app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used gulp node sass yet, but have found for cli access as well as manual processes, you need include-path items or an importer function, even if you use explicit paths within the import calls.

You should also check to see that what you imported is not all mixins and functions/variables, since they only operate on the include calls that summon them. if you set a variable and never use it, it won't compile css

Also: you are having it watch a recursive path for sass changes, but hard coded the input, try accepting stdin/pipe on the sass task